# What are the Warcraft II Cheats?

Tags: cheats, warcraft-2

I have recently been playing some older PC and DOS based games. I noticed that the Arqade section didn't have *ANY* of the information on Cheats and Unlockables for Warcraft II, so I have posted them below.

Comment: You don't have to write the disclaimer, answering your own question is encouraged if it helps other people :). Just be careful with these list-type questions, they can be frowned upon if they're too open-ended.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I am newer to StackExchange sites and had lots of confusion on a question/answer at a sister site (which resulted in downvotes for no reason) I will no longer put the disclaimer on new questions.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: As far as I know, the Battle.NET edition (Win95/98 version) of Warcraft 2 uses the same cheat codes as the DOS version.

Comment: Self-answering your own question is absolutely fine (and encouraged!) and I love that you've done it here. However, you should make sure it really is a *question* - phrase it the same way you would as if you wanted somebody else to answer it. In this case, something like "How do I use cheat codes in Warcraft II, and what cheat codes exist?" would be appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was going to edit the question to match that but I do not think I can so I will just keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Why would there be a cheat section for this game? Just google warcraft 2 cheat code gives you the blizzard site that provides the codes http://classic.battle.net/war2/cheats.shtml

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**I used to LOVE playing this game!!!**

I also noticed there is no mention from above of which versions the cheat codes work on (and which they dont). I only mention this because the first 'demo' version, the commercial version, and the post-expansion versions did not all have all the codes listed in the answer that was here.

I have found a reference and added the versions they work with below:

To use a cheat code, press the [enter] key, type in the code (before the -), and press enter again.

**Warcraft II: Battle.net Edition**

**Effect: Password**

- 10000 gold and 5000 oil/lumber: *glittering prizes*
- 5000 oil: *spycob*
- 5000 oil: *valdez*
- Fast lumber harvest: *hatchet*
- Feif message: *day*
- Full map: *on screen*
- Funky music: *disco*
- Go Bruins message: *ucla*
- God mode: *it is a good day to die*
- Insatnt victory: *unite the clans*
- Magic upgrades: *every little thing she does*
- Multiplayer surrender: *allowsync*
- Play after mission victory: *never a winner*
- Skip Mission: *tigerlily*
- Super fast building: *make it so*
- Unlock all buildings and upgrades: *free buildings*
- Upgrade everything: *deck me out*

**Warcraft II: Beyond the Dark Portal Cheats**

**Effect: Password**

- Entire map: *on screen*
- Extended Play: *never a winner*
- Extra Gold: *glittering prizes*
- Fast Build: *make it so*
- Go Bruins message: *ulca*
- God Mode: *it is a good day to die*
- Instant Loss: *you pitiful worm*
- instant win: *unite the clans*
- Laser Show: *netprof*
- Lumber: *hatchet*
- Magic upgrades: *every little thing she does*
- More Oil: *valdez*
- Music: *disco*

**I also remember that Angry if you continuously click on your human/orc units, they will get mad and impatient with you; but If you continuously click on the sheep, they will say 'baaa ram you' and explode!**

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have some of the codes I was missing, and I almost forgot about the exploding sheep XD

Comment: How do they work ? do you have to input them somewhere ?

Comment: Also I noticed that the case (Valdez vs valdez for example) is not alwways the same, is it normal ?

Comment: @WizLiz. I have edited the answer to show you push enter to put in the cheat. Also, I apologize about the Uppercase/Lowercase. All cheats should be in all lowercase (you don't need to hit shift)

Comment: every little thing she does is Magic.  I forgot about that.

Comment: I'm proud at myself for how many of these I remembered off the top of my head.

Answer (score 8):

To use a cheat code, press the [enter] key, type in the code (before the -), and press enter again. 
*These codes affect all players equally in multi-player games.*

1. Deck me out - Gives you all the weapon/armor upgrades.
2. Disco - Plays the hidden track "I'm a medieval man".
3. Every little thing she does - Gives you all spell upgrades and infinite mana.
4. Glittering prizes - 10,000 gold, 5000 lumber, and 5000 oil for you AND opponent.
5. Hatchet - Cut down trees in 2 chops for you AND opponent.
6. It is a good day to die - Invincible to enemy attacks (except for Tornado, Blizzard, or Death and Decay) and do more damage to enemy.
7. Make it so - Speeds up building and unit production for you AND opponent.
8. Noglues - Disables magic traps (orc traps).
9. On screen - Shows you the whole map.
10. There can be only one - Takes you to the campaign victory sequence.
11. Tigerlily - Enables level jumping. Use Human # and Orc # to jump levels where # is the level you want to go to. For Expansion pack levels type x before the levels (i.e., "xorc10")
12. Unite the clans - Win the scenario instantly.

**Cheat Without Getting Caught**
If you want to use codes to beat the game, but don't like to be ranked "cheater", you can get as far ahead in the game as you want using cheats, then save your game. Quit WarCraft II, then restart it and load your saved game.